# React router grab URL segment in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router

I'm using a simple router in React

```
  <Router>
    <div>                   
       <Switch>
         <Route path="/" component={ Home } exact /> 
         <Route path="/contact" component={ Contact } />   
         <Route path="/:slug" component={ Post } />                       
        </Switch> 
    </div>
  </Router>
```

I'm pulling posts from a blog using REST and have a router component named Post for single blog posts. Any Route that doesn't match with `home` or `contact`, uses the `post` component.

How can I get or pass the route slug/url segment in the Post component? For example if the url segment/slug is `/some-blog-post-title`, I want to retrieve it, preferably using a React Router function/method if it exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the parameters in the `props.match.params` object. To get your `:slug` parameter you would write `props.match.params.slug`.

**Example**

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPost(this.props.match.params.slug);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.match.params.slug !== this.props.match.params.slug) {
      this.getPost(this.props.match.params.slug);
    }
  }

  getPost = slug => {
    // ...
  };

  render() {
    return <h2>{this.props.match.params.slug}</h2>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! The only problem is that the Post route is being ignored in the router switch if added below other routes with specific components. If I add it above them it works but the routes below are ignored. I tried adding `exact` but does not make a difference..

Comment: @CyberJunkie You're welcome! I'm not quite sure I understand. The switch makes sure that only one `Route` in the `Switch` is rendered. Since `path="/:slug"` work as a wildcard for all routes, you can't have e.g. `/contact` below it since that would fit inside `/:slug`.

Comment: I placed `/contact` above the wildcard route and it is being rendered but then the wildcard route is not when going to a custom/dynamic path. I have routes with specific components for paths like `/contact` and one component for wildcard paths. I'm not sure how to make both work.

Comment: @CyberJunkie What you have written in your question should work. You might have duplicate `Router` components, or there might be something else that is causing that behavior.

Comment: If this yields undefined, you can use the HOC withRouter such as: `import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";`, then, `const PostWithRouter = withRouter(Post);` This wuld give you access to the `this.props.match` property

Answer (score 4):

If you want to grab urls in a functional component

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import User from './User';
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/user/:userName' component={User} />
                    <Route>
                        <div>Default page</div>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Inside the functional component you can grab it

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
const User = () => {
    const { userName } = useParams();
    return (
        <div>Username: { userName }</div>
    );
}
export default User;
```